# group duplicates with counts

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I need to go through a list of strings and count the number of duplicates and then print the string with the number of occurrences in one line to a file. Here is what I have but I need to only print the string once and its count.

```
    Do
        line = LineInput(1)
        Trim(line)
        If line = temp Then
            counter += 1
        Else
            counter = 1
        End If
        temp = line
        swriter.WriteLine(line & " " & counter.ToString)
        swriter.Flush()

    Loop While Not EOF(1)
```

My brain is just not functioning today..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use something like a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) to count the strings.

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Do
  line = LineInput(1)
  line = Trim(line)
  If dict.ContainsKey(line) Then
     dict(line) += 1
  Else
     dict.Add(line, 1)
  End If
Loop While Not EOF(1)
```

And then print out the elements in the dictionary

```
For Each line As String In dict.Keys
  swriter.WriteLine(line & " " & dict(line))
  swriter.Flush()
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use LINQ:

```
Dim dups = From x In IO.File.ReadAllLines("TextFile1.txt") _
              Group By line Into Group _
              Where Group.Count > 1 _
              Let count = Group.Count() _
              Order By count Descending _
              Select New With { _
                  Key .Value = x, _
                  Key .Count = count _
              }

For Each d In dups
    swriter.WriteLine(String.Format("duplicate: {0} count: {1}", d.Value, d.Count))
    swriter.Flush()
Next
```